# How to customize Jena ARQ query engine to add additional triple pattern

Tags: design-patterns, sparql, customization, jena, arq

Given the following triples describe **Forklift1 location at the different times**:

```
:forklift1 
   :location :station1, :dockdoor1;
   :9305fc5f-d43d :station1;
   :a4e9-2bcd5b97 :dockdoor1;
  .
:9305fc5f-d43d a :location;
   :createdDate "2022-01-02T10:00:00.000-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime; 
   :expiryDate "2022-01-03T14:00:00.000-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime; 
  .
:a4e9-2bcd5b97 a :location;
   :createdDate "2022-01-03T14:00:00.000-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime; 
  .
```

To retrieve Forklift1's **current location**, a SPARQL query is:

```
select ?o where { 
    :forklift1 :location ?o 
    optional{:forklift1 ?px ?o. ?px a :location. optional{?px :createdDate ?createdDate} optional {?px :expiryDate ?expiryDate}}
    filter (!bound(?expiryDate)) 
  }

?o :dockdoor1
```

**My goal** is to make Query Engine return **the same result** but with a **much simpler query**:

```
select ?s where { 
    :forklift1 :location ?o.
}

?o :dockdoor1
```

I am using **Jena TBD + ARQ**; I read some documents, it can be done by customizing ARQ Query Engine. For each Triple pattern  `:forklift1 :location ?o`, to programmatically add the new property instance pattern  `optional{:forklift1 ?px ?o. ?px a :location. optional{?px :createdDate ?createdDate} optional {?px :expiryDate ?expiryDate}} filter (!bound(?expiryDate))`. I am not hands on this and don't know where to start.

**Does anyone know how to do this? Your help will move my work forward!**

Comment: your query is overly complicated. `select ?o where { 
    :forklift1 :location ?o FILTER NOT EXISTS { :o :expiryDate ?expiryDate  }}` would be enough.

Comment: other than that, a custom query engine that simply transforms the query before executing would be one way to go, example is here: https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/main/jena-examples/src/main/java/arq/examples/engine/MyQueryEngine.java - you could either append triple patterns on the query structure, but maybe better would be to work on the algebra

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the example! It helps me to start in the right direction.  I will give it a try to transform the query, and modify the algebra expression. BTW, you are right, the query can be simplified, it was for location at any given timeline.